Delay in highlighting accent color of an icon in a TabView
I have a TabView with 2 items in it. First item has a toolbar with button inside it. Whenever this button is tapped, it opens a sheet modal. Whenever I drag this sheet modal to dismiss it, the heart icon experiences lag in reflecting that its the highlighted tab.
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var showSheet = false

var body: some View {
    TabView {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("First Tab")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                        Button {
                            showSheet = true
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "gear")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
                    Text("Sheet view...")
                })
        }
        .tabItem {
            Label("Tab 1", systemImage: "heart")
        }

        Text("Second Tab")
            .tabItem {
                Label("Tab 2", systemImage: "bag")
            }
    }
}}


